# how to remove objects from set irrespective of order

Tags: python-3.x, set

I'm having trouble removing objects from a set.  What i did was, create a test class and store two variables in it.  Its a string variable.  I need to store the objects i create into a set and also, any object where (t.a, t.b) is same as (t.b, t.a).  Hence, whenever i add tuples into my set, i'm having trouble removing the reverse condition.  Is there a way to do this in python?

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.variables = [a, b]

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b))

    def __eq__(self, other: Test):
        return type(self) is type(other) and self.endpoint() == other.endpoint() or 
        self.endpoint() == other.endpoint()[::-1]

    def endpoint(self):
        return (self.a, self.b)

T = Test('A','B')
T2 = Test("B",'A")
result = set()
result.add(T)
result.add(T2)

However, result is showing me both the objects in it as opposed to one.  Is there a way to fix this?  Thanks
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: the order doesn't matter.  it can be either ("A", "B") or ("B", "A") i just want to make sure one of these items are left in the set

Comment: You are adding objects to your set, in order to do what you want, you need to provide a mechanism for the test class to evaluate another instance of test with itself and determine equality or not.